# Request object is empty in exception filter in Nestjs

Tags: nestjs

```js
    @Catch()    
    export class CustomExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {

            catch(e: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost): void {
              const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
                const request = ctx.getRequest();
                console.log('req object from custom exception filter', request);
            }
        }
```

The request object in above custom exception filter is empty.Though the request object is not empty in interceptor which runs before this exception filter

Comment: Can you share a bit more about what's happening in the request lifecycle. What it looks like in the interceptor, what context you're working with, maybe what the exception is. Does the class properly have a `@Catch()` decorator?

Comment: yes, the class has @Catch() decorator. The exception filter is getting invoked. Let me update question. And there is no problem with interceptor. Even if i remove interceptor, i can see that the request object is empty {}